# pyodbc 3 times slower than direct SQL

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc, jtds

I have some Python code that uses pyodbc to talk to a SQL Server database. In that code I do an `insert into ...`.

That query takes 3 times longer to run when invoked from Python with pyodbc than when run with direct SQL. In both cases, I am running from the same machine over the same network talking to the same SQL Server.

The only difference I can find is the driver. When I run the direct SQL the client I have uses the driver `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver jtds12.jar` where as pyodbc uses `{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}`.

Could this be the cause of the difference? Is there a different driver I can use with pyodbc that would be faster?

Comment: Are you talking about executing one single-row `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...` statement? When you say "3 times slower" is it a matter of 15 seconds vs. 5 seconds, or more like 0.3 seconds vs. 0.1 seconds?

Comment: No it's many rows. using `INSERT INTO xxxx SELECT * FROM yyyy` On one system we have 1,667 rows and the timing are direct sql 1.7s pyodbc 4.6s. On another system we have 15,000 rows and it's 15s vs 48s

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. Running the query `INSERT INTO dbo.MegaMirror SELECT * FROM dbo.MillionRows` via jTDS 1.3.1 and via pyodbc/msodbcsql17.dll both take between 33 and 35 seconds on my remote test server. I also verified that the `autocommit` setting in pyodbc does not seem to make any significant difference.

Comment: Thanks for trying to reproduce it. I should have mentioned that what I am selecting from is a view. Maybe that is why it's different.

Comment: Yes, I just confirmed that the fact it's a view is the issue. With a table the sql and pyodbc are the same.

Comment: I just tried `CREATE VIEW dbo.MillionRowsView AS SELECT * FROM dbo.MillionRows` and `INSERT INTO dbo.MegaMirror SELECT * FROM dbo.MillionRowsView` and the execution times for jTDS and pyodbc were essentially identical. There's something else going on here.

Comment: In my case the view has a lot of code behind it that hits many tables. Been doing more testing and I found that if I set the isolation level to READ_UNCOMMITTED in pyodbc I get the same performance in both. But that makes no sense as by default both use READ_COMMITTED. And furthermore, with pyodbc using READ_COMMITTED and a table the performance is the same.

Comment: Consider opening an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues) to see if one of the pyodbc devs has an idea as to what's going on.